# Implementing virtual currency is against latest apple guidelines?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore, ios

Iam thinking about implementing virtual currency for my book reader app . But before implementing the virtual currency i did a few r&d and still am not clear about the apple guidelines for virtual currency and its itunes review .

After a some googling works i found this which now confuses me a lot .Because am not using bitcoins or any other accepted virtual currency . Am using a virtual currency built for my app alone . Which can be used to buy paid books .

> Apple announced at the Conference that it has updated its its App Store Review guidelines, adding a new rule will allow apps in the App Store to use virtual currencies, as long as they are legal.

My question is :

Will apple reject if i implement a virtual currency for my app ? If it doesnt reject how can i implement restore purchase for my app . My app is a book reader app which has a login page via which user can login into the app (not the itunes login) and read their downloaded/bought books.

Answer (score 1):

Apple mention virtual currencies in their [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies):

> Apps may facilitate transmission of approved virtual currencies provided that they do so in compliance with all state and federal laws for the territories in which the app functions

But the only way you are going to get a definitive answer on whether Apple will accept or reject your app with your own virtual currency is to ask Apple.

Comment: How can i ask apple about this issue ?